# How to reuse Kendo UI Components for a template? Attribute ".name" gives multiple HTML-elements the exact same ID in the DOM

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a reusable template of Kendo UI buttons and dropdowns.

**The purpose is to have 1 Template.cshtml file and hide/show certain parts of that file wherever I want to use them.**

Some functions (onclick on the buttons) will be commonly used and therefore need to check for the visibility of certain HTML-elements. Other functions (selection of dropdowns) will only be used once or twice in the entire application. However I still want these rarely used components inside my template and the display will be set to "none".

For the implementation of the template into my ASP.NET MVC application I am using the razor syntax:

```
@Html.Action("myTemplate", "Controller")
```

This action returns my partial view:

```
    public ActionResult myTemplate()
    {
        return PartialView("Template");
    }
```

In my View I use this sample-code **in ASP.NET MVC syntax** from the Kendo UI demo page: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/index

Template.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("color")                       // this sets the elements ID in the DOM
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Black",
              Value = "1"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Orange",
              Value = "2"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Grey",
              Value = "3"
          }
      })
      .Value("1")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
)
```

My template works fine if I only use it once inside my entire application (which is the contrary of the purpose of a "template").

If I use my template twice (or more often) on the same page, then the ID #color is used several times on the same page.

**Here is how I want to use my template:**

1. I really need to reuse my template a lot (far more than once). Some elements (buttons, dropdowns, ...) of the template will be set to "display: none" in some parts of the DOM.
2. If I need a few elements of my template, then I want to embed the entire template and show what I need and hide the elements that I don't need.
3. Some elements of my template are "common" and will use common JavaScript functions. Other parts of my template will only have 1 specified function (onclick) and they will be set to "display: none" almost all the time.
4. I do not want to use IDs more than once inside the DOM
5. I have no problem if classes are used more than once inside the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I am able to accomplish this as follows:
1. Create a model called color.cs

```
    public class Color
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

2. The controller

   ```
   public ActionResult MultipleControls()
   {
       var colors = new List<Color>();
       colors.Add(new Color() { Name = "Pink0"});
       colors.Add(new Color() { Name = "Pink1" });
       colors.Add(new Color() { Name = "Pink2" });
       colors.Add(new Color() { Name = "Pink3" });
       return View(colors);
   }
   ```
3. MultipleControls.cshtml page. In this page you can provide a unique name as I am concatenating each color's name.

   ```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
    @model List<WebApplication1.Models.Color>

    @foreach (var color in Model)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => color,"Color"+color.Name)
    }
   ```
4. Create the following EditorTemplate `Color.cshtml`. The template .Name property is using `@Model.Name` so it generate a unique id every time.

   ```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
    @model WebApplication1.Models.Color   

    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
     .Name(@Model.Name)
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Value")
     .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
     .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
         new SelectListItem() {
             Text = "Black",
             Value = "1"
         },
         new SelectListItem() {
             Text = "Orange",
             Value = "2"
         },
         new SelectListItem() {
             Text = "Grey",
             Value = "3"
         }
     })
     .Value("1")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%"})
      )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is way late but I just tackled this so thought I'd leave my solution 
here for a future viewer.

ViewBag can be utilized to pass in a name.

In Template.cshtml:

`@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name(ViewBag.Name)`

In the containing view:

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.someProperty, "Template", new { Name = "mycontrol" })`